# Faster way to split a large CSV file evenly by Groups into smaller CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file, awk

I'm sure there is a better way for this but I am drawing a blank. I have a CSV file in this format. The ID column is sorted so everything is grouped together at least:

```
Text                 ID
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text3, CCCC
this is sample text4, DDDD
this is sample text4, DDDD
this is sample text5, EEEE
this is sample text5, EEEE
this is sample text6, FFFF
this is sample text6, FFFF
```

What I want to do is split the CSV fast across X amount of smaller CSV files fast. So if X==3, then AAAA would go into "1.csv", BBBB would go into "2.csv", CCCC would go into "3.csv" and the next group would loop back around and go into "1.csv".

The groups vary in size so a hardcoded split by numbers won't work here.

Is there a faster way to split these reliably then my current method which just uses Pandas groupby in Python to write them?

```
    file_ = 0
    num_files = 3

    for name, group in df.groupby(by=['ID'], sort=False):

        file_+=1
        group['File Num'] = file_

        group.to_csv(file_+'.csv',index=False, header=False, mode='a')

        if file_ == num_files:

            file_ = 0
```

This is a python based solution but I am open to stuff using `awk` or bash if it gets the job done.

EDIT:

For clarification, I want the groups split across a fixed amount of files I can set.

In this case, 3. (So x = 3). The first group (AAAA) would go into 1.csv, the 2nd into 2.csv, the third into 3.csv and then for the fourth group, it would loop back and insert it into 1.csv. etc.

Example output 1.csv:

```
Text                 ID
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text4, DDDD
this is sample text4, DDDD
```

Example output 2.csv:

```
Text                 ID
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text5, EEEE
this is sample text5, EEEE
```

Example output 3.csv:

```
Text                 ID
this is sample text3, CCCC
this is sample text6, FFFF
this is sample text6, FFFF
```

Comment: Does your `ID` column is always sorted values? As per shown samples.

Comment: Yes, the ID column is sorted. Forgot to clarify that.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your real dataset? A quick test on all provided answers show me that python is quite faster. Can you test on your dataset?

Comment: @mozway I updated the first script in my answer to not continually open/close files to avoid a "too many open files" error (I suspect the python script was faster as it isn't doing that either) as I don't expect that'll be necessary for this application, please try the speed test again with that as it should be noticeably faster than it was when it was opening/closing each file on every change of the last field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    hdr = $0
    next
}
$NF != prev {
    out = (((blockCnt++) % X) + 1) ".csv"
    if ( blockCnt <= X ) {
        print hdr > out
    }
    prev = $NF
}
{ print > out }
```

```
$ awk -v X=3 -f tst.awk input.csv
```

```
$ head [0-9]*.csv
==> 1.csv <==
Text                 ID
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text, AAAA
this is sample text4, DDDD
this is sample text4, DDDD

==> 2.csv <==
Text                 ID
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text2, BBBB
this is sample text5, EEEE
this is sample text5, EEEE

==> 3.csv <==
Text                 ID
this is sample text3, CCCC
this is sample text6, FFFF
this is sample text6, FFFF
```

If `X` was some large enough number that you exceed your system limit for concurrently open files and you start getting a "too many open files" error then you'd need to use GNU awk as it handles that internally or change the code to only have 1 file open at a time:

```
NR==1 {
    hdr = $0
    next
}
$NF != prev {
    close(out)
    out = (((blockCnt++) % X) + 1) ".csv"
    if ( blockCnt <= X ) {
        print hdr > out
    }
    prev = $NF
}
{ print >> out }
```

or implement your own way of managing how many files are open concurrently.

---

EDIT: here's what the suggestion by @PaulHodges in the comments would result in a script like:

```
NR == 1 {
    for ( i=1; i <= X; i++ ) {
        print > (i ".csv")
    }
    next
}
$NF != prev {
    out = (((NR-1) % X) + 1) ".csv"
    prev = $NF
}
{ print > out }
```

Comment: Would moving the `blockCnt` test to a `BEGIN` block to write the headers of the known set of output files make a relevant difference in speed for a big input file?

Comment: @PaulHodges yes, that'd make it slightly faster but then you;d need to add a call to getline to read the header but redirect it's input to be from a file since awk hasn't opened the input yet and then the file would be reopened with that header line still present in the main loop so you'd have to add `NR==1 { next}` or similar. Given all that, it'd be better done in an `NR==1` section. I just added a script like that to the end of my answer - the only potential downside is it'll always create X output files even if there are fewer than X IDs in the input.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -v X=3 '
FNR == 1 {   # save 1st record as header 
   hdr = $0
   next
}
p != $NF {   # ID field changes, move to new output csv file 
   close(fn)
   fn = ((n++ % X) + 1)".csv" # construct new file name
}
!seen[fn]++ {                 # do we need to print header
   print hdr > fn 
}
{
   print >> fn                # append each record to output
   p = $NF                    # save last field in variable p
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following code. As mentioned considering last column is sorted as per shown samples.

```
awk -v x="3" '
BEGIN{
  count=1
  outFile=count".csv"
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
prev!=$NF && prev{
  close(outFile)
  count++
  outFile=count".csv"
}
{
  print >> (outFile)
  prev=$NF
}
x==count{ count=1 }
' Input_file
```

Comment: This looks like what I want, only thing missing is "So if X==3, then AAAA would go into "1.csv", BBBB would go into "2.csv", CCCC would go into "3.csv" and the next group would loop back around and go into "1.csv"."

Comment: @GreenGodot, could you please do let me know what is `x==3` here? Thank you

Comment: We are splitting the groups across a fixed amount of files I can set. In this case, 3. (So x = 3). The first group would go into 1.csv, the 2nd into 2.csv, the thirs into 3.csv and then for the fourth group, it would loop back and insert it into 1.csv. If that makes sense?

Comment: @GreenGodot, so you mean you don't want to consider last column at all in your question?

Comment: @GreenGodot, could you please do check my updated code once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13. Thanks for your patience but in practice, when i try to run your code, I get "line 19: syntax error at or near if"

Answer (score 0):

Using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) modulo the number of desired groups (`N`):

```
N = 3

for i, g in df.groupby(pd.factorize(df['ID'])[0]%N):
    g.to_csv(f'chunk{i+1}.csv', index=False)
```

Output files:

```
# chunk1.csv
Text,ID
this is sample text,AAAA
this is sample text,AAAA
this is sample text,AAAA
this is sample text,AAAA
this is sample text,AAAA
this is sample text4,DDDD
this is sample text4,DDDD

# chunk2.csv
Text,ID
this is sample text2,BBBB
this is sample text2,BBBB
this is sample text2,BBBB
this is sample text5,EEEE
this is sample text5,EEEE

# chunk3.csv
Text,ID
this is sample text3,CCCC
this is sample text6,FFFF
this is sample text6,FFFF
```

##### timings

Tested on 14 million rows:

```
15.8 s ± 687 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

~14s of which is due to I/O

Comparison with other answers (using `time` in the shell):

```
# @mozway as a python script including imports and reading the file
real    0m20,834s

# @RavinderSingh13
real    1m22,952s

# @anubhava
real    1m23,790s

# @Ed Morton (updated code, original solution was 2m58,171s)
real    0m8,599s
```

As a function:

```
import pandas as pd

def split_csv(filename, N=3, id_col='ID', out_basename='chunk'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    for i, g in df.groupby(pd.factorize(df[id_col])[0]%N):
        g.to_csv(f'{out_basename}{i+1}.csv', index=False)

split_csv('my_file.csv', N=3)
```

Comment: It's impossible for anubhavas script to run twice as fast as my original script as they're both doing the same opens/closes/writes but mine is doing fewer additional instructions for each input line. They should be very close to identical in performance with mine being very slightly faster. My modified script which isn't opening/closing the output files every time the output file changes should be noticabley faster.

Comment: When I save the bottom script in your answer in a file named `mozway.py` and try to run it as `python mozway.py` I get this syntax error: `File "mozway.py", line 6` `g.to_csv(f'{out_basename}{i+1}.csv', index=False)`  up-arrow pointing at the `'` at the end of `.csv'` `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I don't see any obvious issues and don't know python well enough to debug it. I'm running `Python 2.7.15` so maybe it's a python 2 vs 3 issue? If so, I can't install python 3 as my computer is controlled by our IT dept.

Comment: @EdMorton python 2 has been deprecated for years (the error you got is due to the f-string which only exists since python3.6), I used python 3.11 and pandas 2.0.3. Regarding your timing vs that of anubhavas, feel free to compare by yourself but in any case both are much slower than python in my hands

Comment: I know about python 2 being deprecated but sometimes there's organizational or contractual reasons for being required to use it and that's the situation I'm in, nothing I can do about it. Oh well.

Comment: Please re-run your timing test for my original script as, like I say, the results you posted are simply impossible so something went wrong first time around (maybe you ran it on `*.csv` so it picked up all of the previously generated output files in addition to the input file? idk but **something** is off). Also please do try timing for my modified script that isn't trying to open/close output files frequently so we're comparing similar awk functionality against the python functionality.

Comment: @EdMorton of course, I understand, but I don't code anymore in python2 ;) I tested your updated script and it runs in ~10s now

Comment: Great, would you mind updating your answer to replace the stats that are there from my previous script?

Comment: Yes, it's planned, I'm just re-checking the older script although I'm pretty sure I hadn't done a mistake in the timing. But it makes sense, if you reopen the file over and over the behavior is quadratic as you need to reach the end again for each iteration. edit: tested again and it's indeed >2min.

Comment: I created a 15 million line input file using `awk 'NR==1{print; next} {for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++) print | "sort -t, -k2,2"}' input.csv > largeInput.csv` then did 3rd-run timing on anubhava's original script vs my script and the result for anubhavas was `real    0m7.673s
user    0m7.139s
sys     0m0.467s` while mine was `real    0m6.607s
user    0m5.952s
sys     0m0.546s` so very similar with mine slighty faster as expected. I really can't imagine how your timing showed mine running twice as slow - something is going wrong in your tests, I don't know what.

Comment: @EdMorton your can test yourself once you're on another computer. I used pandas and `df2 = pd.concat([df]*1_000_000, ignore_index=True) ; df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].ne(df2['ID'].shift()).cumsum().astype(str).radd('XXX') ; df2.to_csv('split_test.csv', index=False)` to generate the csv with varying IDs (from the original `df`). Then `time awk -v X=3 -f tst.awk split_test.csv` to test your solution.

Comment: The more different IDs in the input the faster mine should run compared to anubhava's as with `!seen[fn]++` they're growing and looking up a hash table containing every ID to decide whether or not to print the header and they're doing it for every input line, while with `$NF != prev { ... if (blockCnt <= X) ...}` I'm just doing an integer comparison and only doing it when the ID changes so I'm using a faster operation and doing it less frequently.

Comment: @EdMorton your method to create the 15M rows file makes little sense, you'll have only 6 consecutive groups. Test on mine, the groups are interleaved which is better to see how the code scales. Regarding the comparison with anubhava, honestly I have no clue, I reported my timings and the method, please use your answer to provide yours  ;)

Comment: The number of groups hardly matters but the smaller number I'm using would favor solutions other than mine. The groups cannot be interleaved - per the OP "The ID column is sorted so everything is grouped together". If they were interleaved I'd recommend running `sort` first. I'd rather not add timings to my answer too since you already have them (so different results would confuse future readers) and I can't run your solution to test it so anything I posted would be incomplete and not comparable to your python result given different processor speeds.

Comment: @EdMorton what I meant is that your file is AAA…BBB…CCC…DDD…EEE…FFF… You should test on AA…B…C…D…E…F…G…H…[…]Z123… WIth only 6 different IDs, you loop over the files very infrequently. Try **many** sorted IDs, not just 6.

Comment: Ah, I see. The awk scripts are all doing mostly the same thing when IDs change (the `prev != $NF` block in each script) so the number of IDs wont make much difference in the relative timing comparisons but here we go... This time I ran `awk 'NR==1{print; next} {for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++) print $0 (i%1000) | "sort -t, -k2,2"}' input.csv` to once again create 15 mil lines of input but now with 6 thousand unique IDs and here's the timing for anubhava: `real    0m36.461s
user    0m8.452s
sys     0m20.311s` and for me: `real    0m34.866s
user    0m5.436s
sys     0m21.922s`.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
group.to_csv(file_+'.csv',index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

you are providing string as 1st argument, however [`to_csv` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) allow you to provide file-like object as 1st argument, in which case you might avoid doing file-opening-related stuff multiple times, consider following simple simple comparison

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
REPEAT = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(100)})
t1 = time.time()
for _ in range(REPEAT):
    df.to_csv('file.csv',index=False,header=False,mode='a')
t2 = time.time()
os.remove('file.csv')
t3 = time.time()
with open('file.csv','a') as f:
    for _ in range(REPEAT):
        df.to_csv(f,index=False,header=False)
t4 = time.time()
print('Using filename',t2-t1)
print('Using filehandle',t4-t3)
```

gives output

```
Using filename 0.35850977897644043
Using filehandle 0.2669696807861328
```

Observe that 2nd way take around 75% time of 1st way, so whilst it is faster it is still same order of magnitude.